# dynamically adding derived column in SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, flat-file, derived-column

I have a scenario where my source can be on different versions of our database as a result the in source file I could have different number of columns while my destination have defined number of columns.
now 
what we are trying to do is:

> load data from source to flat files. move them to central server and
>   then load that data into central database. but if any column is
>   missing in flat file i need to add derived column.

what is the best way to do this?? how can i dynamically add derived columns?

Comment: If you set up your package to load data from a file with seven columns and it finds a file with six columns your package with fail. You may wish to investigate BIML which allows you to autogenerate a package per file.

Comment: As @Nick.McDermaid says, why add derived columns dynamically when you can create the entire SSIS package dynamically? Refer - [Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/130470/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this with BiMLScript as other have suggested in comments, or you can write a script task that reads the file, analyzes the contents, and imports it.  Yet another option would be to bulk import the file as is to a staging table (that would have to be dropped and re-created everytime) and write a stored procedure that analyzes the DDL and contents, and imports data to the destination table.